# Loop over subsets in frame with customised variance function

Tags: r

Dataframe structure:

```
id_group <- c(a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,d,d,d)
group_mean <- c(3,3,3,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,3,3)
value <- c(2,3,3,4,2,2,4,4,3,2,2,3)
df <- data.frame(id_group, group_mean, value)
```

I'm new to r and am trying to piece together appropriate code given many answers searched on stackoverflow.
I am trying to determine variance for each group (group_id) given a predetermined mean - therefore I cannot just use var(). Instead I am creating a custom function for variance.

how do I combine the two codes that I have (one for the loop and one for variance calculation)

Variance:

```
x = df$value 
variance <- function(x){
  x = as.numeric(x)
  x = na.omit(x)
  m = mean(x)
  return(
    sum((x-m)^2, na.rm = TRUE)/(length(x) - 1)
  )
}
```

The loop:

```
uniq <- unique(unlist(df$group_id))
for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
data_1 <- subset(df, group_id == uniq[i])
#insert function}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate`/`tapply` to apply `variance` for each `id_group`.

```
aggregate(value~id_group, df, variance)
```

In `dplyr` you can follow :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id_group) %>% summarise(variance = variance(value))

#  id_group variance
#* <chr>       <dbl>
#1 a           0.333
#2 b           1.33 
#3 c           0.333
#4 d           0.333
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
library(magrittr)
df %>%
   fgroup_by(id_group) %>%
   fsummarise(variance = fvar(value))
```

-output

```
#  id_group  variance
#1        a 0.3333333
#2        b 1.3333333
#3        c 0.3333333
#4        d 0.3333333
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id_group = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "c", "d", "d", "d"), group_mean = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3), value = c(2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```